# How to install python on my Android GT-P7510?

Tags: root-access, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-tab, python

My Samsung tablet 10.1 GT-P7510 is running Android 4.0.4.

I have root access to the device.

What is the best way to install python on my device.

I have tried [QPython - Python for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy&hl=en) however the pip console does not show any text as I type into it.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: What I did, was to install the Termux app (which is the most close to a Linux terminal). Then, I installed the Python interpreter via `apt install python` from inside Termux.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Thx for the termux app however it is available only for android >= 5.0. Thus I cannot use it

Comment: Pardon, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SL4A. 
Which can help you to run python on Android. https://github.com/kuri65536/sl4a/releases/download/6.1.1/sl4a-r6.1.1-arm-debug.apk

Answer (score -1):

I installed the hackers keyboard and and now I can type into the pip console which is visible.

Silly me.

Comment: Your answer lacks depth. Kindly expound on how you came to diagnose the problem ,solutions and citations.

Comment: I wish I could explain more. 

I was having trouble typing with the samsung inbuilt keyboard on shell terminal therefore started looking for alternatives. 

Stumbled on Hackers Keyboard on Google play. Installed it for my ease and switched to it as the default keyboard and used it for some time on shell terminal.

Went back to QPython pip console on my device and presto there was what I was typing on the screen.

Came back and answered my own question writing 'silly me'